# Declare interface property to be a boolean or a function returning a boolean for a multi page form

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am designing multi-step form control; kind of like a kind of tabbed control.  The form will consist of multiple individual pages.  Some of those pages may appear and disappear based on runtime conditions.  For example, if the user checked a checkbox labeled "Show the hidden page!" on page 2, then page 3 would magically appear.

So I thought to declare an interface that would be used in the programmatic API to define what the pages are:

```
export interface MultiFormPage {
    id: string;  // unique id of this page
    title: string;  // title of this page
    fieldIds: Array<string>;  // fields in this page
    visible: boolean;  // non-visible tabs aren't shown in the page list
    enabled?: boolean;  // non-enabled pages can't be selected
    active?: boolean;   // only the active page is shown
};
```

The `visible` property is the one in question.  As you can see, it's declared as a `boolean` property.  It's simple enough to populate that statically and imperitively, like this: `myControl.addPage({..., visible: true})`

But what I want is to pass along a function that can be evaluated at run-time to determine at any given moment if that page should be `visible`. Something like:

```
@Component()
export class ParentControl {

  iWasTriggered(): boolean {
    return this.formComponent.form['trigger'];
  }
};
```

...and then, of course:

`myControl.addPage({..., visible: this.iWasTriggered});`

But the compiler complains:

> Types of property 'visible' are incompatible.
>           Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Yeah, I totally get that.  What I don't get is how do I accomplish what I want to accomplish?

I've tried a number of things in the code (such as changing the declaration for `visible` to `visible?: (): boolean;`, etc) , but I haven't been able to divine the magical incantation I need.

How do I accomplish my goal of setting an interface property to be a function that returns a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
visible: boolean | () => boolean;
```

Then you'll need to use a type guard to check which type it is:

```
addPage(props: MultiFormPage): void {
    let visible: boolean;

    if (typeof props.visible === "function") {
        visible = props.visible();
    } else {
        visible = props.visible;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

As `visible: boolean | () => boolean` is fine with the compiler, you can do this:

```
type ReturnBoolean = () => boolean;
...
visible: string | ReturnBoolean;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ReturnBoolean%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MultiFormPage%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fieldIds%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20visible%3A%20string%20%7C%20ReturnBoolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20enabled%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20active%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B))

Or:

```
visible: boolean | (() => boolean)
```

Comment: +1: `() => boolean` was, indeed, the magical incantation I was seeking.  However my compiler is quite displeased with the alternation (`boolean | () => boolean`)  Says it was expecting a type, and I gave it gibber.  This random link from 2014 says wasn't part of the language in 2014.

Comment: Is the alternation syntax you provided correct?  Is it even legal?

Comment: It's part of the language alright, it's called [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). The compiler wrote "gibber"? What was the error message?

Comment: Nope, 'gibber' was my trnasliteration.  Here's what it actually said:

Comment: [at-loader] Checking finished with 3 errors
[at-loader] src\app\components\ui\form\multiform.component.ts:15:31
    TS1110: Type expected.

Comment: Column 31 is the open paren after the vertical bar.  The question I'm wondering is, although TS has Union Types (confusing name to an old C++ guy), can you use them in an `interface`?

Comment: Aha!  This works:  `checkVisible?: boolean | (() => boolean);`  If you wouldn't mind editing your post, I'll accept.  Thx.

Comment: Right. I've edited my answer, it also shows another way to do it using type alias.